# Hash tables: Whats the best way to mark a bucket empty?

Tags: hashtable

Ran into an annoying problem - I need some way to tell if the bucket I'm trying to fill is empty or not (the buckets are stored as an array of value type structs for key-value pairs).

If I were to reserve a key value for marking things empty then that would just mean that some data unfortunate enough to stumble on that hash value would never be accessible.
On the other hand, including a boolean in the KVP struct would increase the size of the struct from 16 to 24, (such a waste and I'm tight on memory as it is). Has anybody figured out a good solution for this?

Comment: I sense an XY problem here. Your bucket can either be a linked list of nodes, in which case an empty bucket is simply denoted by a null link, or else it's an array of nodes, in which case it has length 0. Also, you did not state which programming language you're using.

Comment: I don't have buckets in that sense, each "bucket" is one array item (not dynamically allocated). C++

Comment: What happens if you have bucket collision? You need for each bucket to be able to hold multiple entries.

Comment: I first seek the array for the next open slot, if I don't find one for x amount of tries, I put it in the overflow list, when overflow list is full i resize the table and start over. I usually end up with ~75% of the table filled before I have to resize.

Comment: I think I just figured it out though! I'm going to reserve 0 hash for empty and store all the things that hash to 0 in a separate little list. Booyah no performance hit!

Comment: Scratch that, it just occurred to me that only one element can have the exact key of 0 so i only need to make one. Performance gains 20%, memory footprint down 33%!

Comment: Tested the performance vs std::unordered_map which took 61s and 800mb to store and retrieve 10m kvp's of uint64_t, mine took  4.5s and 200mb. I'm happy :D

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem that is as intrinsic to hash tables as collisions.  A related problem is dealing with deleting from a hash table, again, in the context of collisions.  There's no solution that doesn't involve some compromise in performance, so it's pretty common to see hash table implementations that have a particular key that is illegal.

By far the most direct solution is to just special-case the key value that you're using to mean empty.  That is, if the user is trying to store a key value 0, you just put it in a special array you keep around for that purpose.

Really lame hash tables that only work with pointers don't usually have this issue, since you can always find a pointer value which the caller can't pass in (such as a pointer to an object you own).  Obviously hash tables using linked lists or array elements don't have this problem either, but then, there's a massive performance penalty for those.

You could probably find some clever way to encode it inside the table itself, by using multiple elements.  The only way this would be better is if its somehow unified with deleted element handling or something else, so it would be free or faster than checking some separate list.